# SQLite (1) near "M": syntaxs error

Tags: android, database, sqlite, insert

I've created this table in android:

```
     String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE " + db_NAME + " ("
                        + row_ID + " INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                        + row_NAME + " TEXT, "
                        + row_EMAIL + " TEXT, "
                        + row_WEBSITE + " TEXT, "
                        + row_TELEPHONE1 + " TEXT, "
                        + row_TELEPHONE2 + " TEXT, "
                        + row_TELEPHONE3 + " TEXT, "
                        + row_TELEPHONE4 + " TEXT, "
                        + row_TELEPHONE5 + " TEXT;";
    db_name.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
```

and I'm trying to isert the following data:

Name: Ahlam M. Hussain

Email: ahlam@ahlam.ahlam

Website: www.ahlam.com

telephone#1: 123456789

telephone#2: 0987654321

telephone#3:

telephone#4:

telephone#5:

using the following string:

```
     String sql_entry = String.format("Insert into %s (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);",tab_NAME, row_NAME, row_EMAIL, row_WEBSITE, row_TELEPHONE1, row_TELEPHONE2, row_TELEPHONE3, row_TELEPHONE4, row_TELEPHONE5, name, email, website, telephone1, telephone2, telephone3,telephone4, telephone5);
     ourDatabase.execSQL(sql_entry);
```

where : `( row_NAME, row_EMAIL, row_WEBSITE, row_TELEPHONE1, row_TELEPHONE2, row_TELEPHONE3, row_TELEPHONE4, row_TELEPHONE5)` are the columns names'

and : `(name, email, website, telephone1, telephone2, telephone3,telephone4, telephone5)` are the data intended to be inserted to the database

when I run the application, I got an error says:

```
      SQLiteLog        (1) near "M" : syntax error
```

so what is the problem ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose the non-numeric value in single quotes.

```
String sql_entry = String.format("Insert into %s (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
 +" values ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",
  tab_NAME, row_NAME, row_EMAIL, row_WEBSITE, row_TELEPHONE1, row_TELEPHONE2, 
  row_TELEPHONE3, row_TELEPHONE4, row_TELEPHONE5, name, email, website, 
  telephone1, telephone2, telephone3,telephone4, telephone5);
```

Answer (score 1):

You left out the `'` characters to enclose strings...

The query should read:

```
Insert into %s (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) values ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s');
```

So creating the query string itself should look like:

```
 String sql_entry = String.format("Insert into %s (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) values ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s');",
tab_NAME, row_NAME, row_EMAIL, row_WEBSITE, row_TELEPHONE1, row_TELEPHONE2, row_TELEPHONE3, row_TELEPHONE4, row_TELEPHONE5, 
 name, email, website, telephone1, telephone2, telephone3,telephone4, telephone5);
```

By the way, when developing an application, I always log the SQL queries I create without using frameworks - it is easy to make mistakes like this.